# Is the term "Lagrangian density" specific to spacetime?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, spacetime, action

Wikipedia talks about Lagrangian densities [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian). But they never actually say whether they're just applying the concept to spacetime or that Lagrangian density is the analog for Lagrangians but for spacetime.

**Can someone clarify what the definition of a Lagrangian density is and whether or not it is a concept specific to spacetime?**

Comment: Specific to spacetime as opposed to?

Comment: Well, it could be a mathematical term that might be used to mean something else and spacetime just one application. I didn't know. Your answer I think clarifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*No,* the integration in the action functional $S=\int_M d^nx {\cal L}$  (with the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ as integrand) does *not* have to be over physical spacetime. Obviously the Lagrangian formalism works for any manifold $M$, depending on the specific application. In e.g. string theory the manifold $M$ is a (super) [Riemann surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface); not physical spacetime.

Comment: Wow that's amazing! I never understood how we did Lagrangians in string theory over such complex surfaces but this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: How is this different from a Lagrangian though? Are Lagrangians only permitted over single variables like the real numbers?

Comment: Yes, $S= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~ L$, where the integration variable $t$ does not have to be physical time.